# Can a lambda be invoked by an ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I currently have a service running with ECS + Fargate. Now I want to create a lambda, which would be triggered synchronously by an ECS task in the previous service.

Is it possible to trigger a lambda by an ECS task? I have come across a [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/) in which Lambda is used to invoke ECS, but not the other way around.

Comment: Lambdas can be invoked from the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-sync.html) or from the AWS SDK. Since we don't know what language are you using for the ECS task, we can not really guide you to the documentation. Moreover, you can expose the lambda as a REST endpoint and call it as such from the task.

Answer (score 4):

"You can invoke Lambda functions directly with the Lambda console, the Lambda API, the AWS SDK, the AWS CLI, and AWS toolkits." So you'll have to decide which method is going to work best for your ECS tasks. You will need to set the correct permissions so that your ECS will be able to invoke the Lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invoke Lamda in an async manner, you can publish a message to SQS from your ECS task and SQS can trigger the Lamda on message receive.